# Bash script key/value pair regardless of bash version

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am writing a curl bash script to test webservices. I will have `file_1` which would contain the URL paths

```
/path/to/url/1/{dynamic_path}.xml
/path/to/url/2/list.xml?{query_param}
```

Since the values in between {} is dynamic, I am creating a separate file, which will have values for these params. the input would be in key-value pair i.e.,

```
dynamic_path=123
query_param=shipment
```

By combining two files, the input should become

```
/path/to/url/1/123.xml
/path/to/url/2/list.xml?shipment
```

This is the background of my problem. Now my questions

I am doing it in bash script, and the approach I am using is first reading the file with parameters and parse it based on '=' and store it in key/value pair. so it will be easy to replace i.e., for each url I will find the substring between {} and whatever the text it comes with, I will use it as the key to fetch the value from the array

My approach sounds okay (at least to me) BUT, I just realized that

`declare -A input_map` is only supported in bashscript higher than 4.0. Now, I am not 100% sure what would be the target environment for my script, since it could run in multiple department.

Is there anything better you could suggest ? Any other approach ? Any other design ?

P.S:
This is the first time i am working on bash script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a risky way to do it: Assuming the values are in a file named "values"

```
. values
eval "$( sed 's/^/echo "/; s/{/${/; s/$/"/' file_1 )"
```

Basically, stick a dollar sign in front of the braces and transform each line into an echo statement.

More effort, with awk:

```
awk '
    NR==FNR {split($0, a, /=/); v[a[1]]=a[2]; next} 
    (i=index($0, "{")) && (j=index($0,"}")) {
        key=substr($0,i+1, j-i-1)
        print substr($0, 1, i-1) v[key] substr($0, j+1)
    }
' values file_1
```

Comment: +1 for awk command. I was also going to post that risky approach but then stopped thinking it was too risky.

Comment: whats the risk in it ? and can someone break it down ?

Comment: Imagine some adds a line to the file_1: `/path/to/$(echo this is a malicious command)`

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. You seem to think of putting all inputs in a hashmap, and then iterate over that hashmap. In shell scripting it's more common and practical to process things as a stream using pipelines.

For example, your inputs could be in a csv file:

```
123,shipment
345,order
```

Then you could process this file like this:

```
while IFS=, read path param; do
    sed -e "s/{dynamic_path}/$path/" -e "s/{query_param}/$param/" file_1
done < input.csv
```

The output will be:

```
/path/to/url/1/123.xml
/path/to/url/2/list.xml?shipment
/path/to/url/1/345.xml
/path/to/url/2/list.xml?order
```

But this is just an example, there can be so many other ways.

You should definitely start by writing a proof of concept and test it on your deployment server. This example should work in old versions of bash too.

Comment: the problem is that assume the first line of csv is 123,shipment however, the first line of file_1 is `/path/to/url/2/list.xml?{query_param}`. If i try to find path in the `URL` I would never find it. I would have to make sure that everything is in order.

Comment: @EmAe I'm not sure if I understood your problem well. I changed the `echo` in the loop to a `sed` and added a sample output.